# .NETCore up to 2.2.3 from 2.2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I updated VS2017 to version 15.9.14 and wanted to update my version .net core to 2.2.3.

I install all need packages
http://joxi.ru/vAWpWBjCgXgOjr

but my VS can't use reference 2.2.3
http://joxi.ru/a2XGlwvIwKw4am

PackageReference not contain version

what wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read [this page](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/3124)

Visual Studio 2017 can't target .NET Core 2.2
If you receive the error message in Visual Studio 2017:

The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.2. Either target .NET Core 2.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.2.

If you downloaded the .NET Core SDK 2.2 between April 2 and April 12, 2019, the main .NET downloads page included only 2.2.2nn. Starting April 12th, a new button marked "Compatible with Visual Studio 2017" is provided to target 2.2.1nn.

Comment: okay, I installed SDK 2.2 compatible with Visual Studio 2017. 
http://joxi.ru/EA4ZdlVtoGolym
http://joxi.ru/RmzVB73CYJYg8m But problem is same. I can use only 2.2.0

Comment: I need at least version 2.2.1

Comment: Me problem was resolved with updating Visual Studio